# toastr notification not work using laravel8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

i use toastr in laravel 8
my code in controller
all my code here  i hope guys some help

```php
$flight = new contact;
        
$flight->name = $request->name;
$flight->email = $request->email;
$flight->message = $request->message;
$flight->save();
        
$notification = array(
    'message' => 'Message send Successfully', 
    'alert-type' => 'success'
);

return redirect('/')->with($notification);
```

and  javascript file

```
<script>
    @if (Session::has('message'))
        var type = "{{ Session::get('alert-type', 'info') }}";
        switch(type)
        {
            case 'info':
                toastr.info("{{ Session::get('message') }}");
                break;
                                
            case 'warning':
                toastr.warning("{{ Session::get('message') }}");
                break;
                        
            case 'success':
                toastr.success("{{ Session::get('message') }}");
                break;
                        
            case 'error':
                toastr.error("{{ Session::get('message') }}");
                break;
        }
    @endif    
</script>
```

after saving data no alert show but the the data exist in database

Answer (score 0):

You're not flashing to session, you're passing in data to the view. Try this instead.

```php
$notification = [
    'message' => 'Message send Successfully', 
    'type' => 'success'
];

session()->flash('notification', $notification);

return redirect('/');
```

and  javascript file

```
<script>
    @if (Session::has('notification'))
        switch('{{ Session::get('notification')['type'] }}')
        {
            case 'info':
                toastr.info('{{ Session::get('notification')['message'] }}');
                break;
                                
            case 'warning':
                toastr.warning('{{ Session::get('notification')['message'] }}');
                break;
                        
            case 'success':
                toastr.success('{{ Session::get('notification')['message'] }}');
                break;
                        
            case 'error':
                toastr.error('{{ Session::get('notification')['message'] }}');
                break;
        }
    @endif    
</script>
```

Comment: i have this error    htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: if there is a way without using JSON